# Error in setting up 2 Vue.js applications in Traefik at subpath level

Tags: vue.js, traefik

I want to serve 2 applications built in Vue.js, both at sub-path like *domain.com/apps/tennis/* and *domain.com/apps/football/*

Both are served behind Traefik with rules like:

```
Host(`domain.com`) && PathPrefix(`/tennis/`) --> Frontend tennis application

Host(`domain.com`) && PathPrefix(`/football/`) --> Frontend football application
```

I use vue-router and have settings like for both applications in their respective router.js:

```
const router =  new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: '/apps/tennis',
  linkActiveClass: 'active',
  linkExactActiveClass: 'exact-active',
  scrollBehavior() {
    return { x: 0, y: 0 };
  },
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      redirect: '/home',
    },
    {
      path: "/home",
      name: "home",
      component: () => import("./views/Home"), // show tennis application home page
    }]
});

const router =  new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: '/apps/football',
  linkActiveClass: 'active',
  linkExactActiveClass: 'exact-active',
  scrollBehavior() {
    return { x: 0, y: 0 };
  },
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      redirect: '/home',
    },
    {
      path: "/home",
      name: "home",
      component: () => import("./views/Home"), // show football application home page
    }]
});
```

Both apps have vue.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: '/tennis/'
};

module.exports = {
  publicPath: '/football/'
};
```

Both applications are not loading on browser and I see the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

Can anyone help setting up two different applications at subpath level in Vue.js? I guess I am getting consfused with base and publicPaths.

Comment: Your routes have a base path of `/apps/<sport>` but your config has a public path of `/<sport>/` so which is it?

Comment: That is my confusion, i.e the usage and diff in routes and config. I want it to be ```/apps/<sport>```

Comment: So why not use that everywhere? Why are you using the non `/apps/` prefixed paths?

Comment: I changed base, publicPath and traefik rule to ```/apps/<sport>```. I still get the error as ```Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'```

Comment: Could ```COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html``` from applications Dockerfile cause any trouble?

Comment: You're going to have to do some debugging. That error means that a request for something that is meant to be JS is actually returning HTML. Look at the requests being made in your browser's _Network_ console and make sure the URLs are correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222243/discussion-between-maopuppets-and-phil).

Comment: @maopuppets Hi, any solution on this?

Comment: @Rizerzero yes, I was able to make this work. Your vue.config should have ```publicPath: '/apps/tennis'``` and ```publicPath: '/apps/football'```. Then router has ```base: '/apps/tennis',``` or ```base: '/apps/football',```. They are served behind ngnix at ```location ^~ /apps/tennis/ {``` and ```location ^~ /apps/football/ {```. Let me know if this works for you!